# django forms result in an poorly idented form

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a sample project in django(1.7.2)/python(2.7)

(1) I am using django forms as below

```
forms.py
class BookAddForm(forms.Form):
  title = forms.CharField(label = "Book Title", max_length=256)
  author = forms.CharField(label = "Author", max_length=256)
  isbn = forms.CharField(label = "ISBN Number", max_length=256)

views.py
...
def add(request):
  form = BookAddForm()
  return render(request, "add_view.html", {'add_view_form': form})
...

add_view.html
....
  <form action="/books/add/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_view_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
....
```

I get a form UI like below screenshot
[image: unindented form]
UPDATE:

```
<form action="/books/add/" method="post">
                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='yEe6xirTklvtAQ0qowBhb8REpFKn4knR' />
                <tr><th><label for="id_title">Book Title:</label></th><td><input id="id_title" maxlength="256" name="title" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_author">Author:</label></th><td><input id="id_author" maxlength="256" name="author" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_isbn">ISBN Number:</label></th><td><input id="id_isbn" maxlength="256" name="isbn" type="text" /></td></tr>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I tried  to use 'as_table', 'as_p' and 'as_li', as mentioned in [forms api outputting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-outputting-html) and none of them helped

(2) I was trying to integrate bootstrap using [django-bootstrap-form module](https://django-bootstrap-form.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). But for some reason, I dont see the style being applied.

(3) I have made my [bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/audiry/crowdlibrary/) public. Pls feel free to patch it and help me in getting my web service styled well.

I am literally blocked on this; any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML for the form?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Added generated html. PTAL

Comment: Yeah, I ain't downloading some strange file. Make a cut down of the generated HTML, specific only to the form, and insert it *inline*, so we can see it.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Done. Inline the generated html

Comment: As catavaran states, you need to wrap it in a table element.

Answer (score 1):

`as_table` outputs `<tr>`/`<th>`/`<td>` tags only.  You should wrap it with `<table>` tag:

```
<form action="/books/add/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    {{ add_view_form.as_table }}
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I tested it in the app from your bitbucket repository. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the `<table>` tag in the generated html from your question's update.

Comment: Yes., @catavaran: I've tried with <table> tag in my template https://bitbucket.org/audiry/crowdlibrary/src/50bbfb76cf515dbeea465d0a2054218f16808515/books/templates/add_view.html?at=master   .But, still not generated in gen. HTML. I'm not sure why, that's my concern i guess

Comment: I cloned your repository and after `python manage.py runserver` I got the perfectly aligned form.  I didn't touch any code or template. See the screenshot in my updated answer.

Comment: hmm... my bad;                                                                                                           I was duplicating a block of template code in two places(bad code smell!); I was constantly trying out in a different template file(add_view.html) when I had to try that out in books_view.html file. When I saw your comment that books/add was working well, I realized that I was updating the wrong template file. I made the changes in books_view.html and it turned out that every thing I reported not working were working nicely. Thanks a lot for cloning my repo and trying out.